Hibernate Upgrade from 5 to 6 Causes PostgreSQL Enum Mapping Error
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable")
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "myId")
    private Long myId;
    
    @Column(name = "myField_change_status")
    @ColumnTransformer(
        write = "?::myField_change_status_enum", // Casts to the PostgreSQL enum type
        read = "myField_change_status::text" // Converts to text on reading
    )
    private MyFieldEnumStatus myFieldStatus;

}

I'm upgrading Hibernate from version 5 to version 6 and encountering issues with mapping PostgreSQL enums in my JPA entity. Previously, I used @Type and @TypeDef annotations to handle enums, but now, with Hibernate 6, these annotations are no longer used.
I'm getting error as
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement \[Error: column myField_change_status is of type myField_change_status_enum but expression is of type character varying Hint: you will need to rewrite or cast the expression\]

